# PHP as JavaScript: get users IP

Tags: javascript, php, ip, tracking

I use this simple script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _mytrack = _mytrack || [];
_mytrack.push(['_setType', 'SOMETYPE']);
_mytrack.push(['_setEmail', 'john@johndoe.com']);

(function() {
var mytrack = document.createElement('script');
_mytrack.type = 'text/javascript';
_mytrack.async = true;
mytrack.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://www' : 'http://www') + '.mytrack.net/tracker.tell.php?i='+_mytrack;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(mytrack, s);
})();
</script>
```

My PHP script (tracker.tell.php) looks like this:

```
header("content-type: application/javascript");
echo "alert('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."');";
```

Now the question is related to the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` because this gives (in an JS alert) the IP of the SERVER and not of the CLIENT.

Comment: Might not be possible to do with PHP because the PHP script runs on the server, not the client. Have you tried/considered using Javascript for this?

Comment: @jonhopkins Of course you can get the remote IP from PHP... how do you think the web server communicates with the client?

Comment: You're probably running a proxy server on your server, yeah?

Comment: Hi @Brad yes I'm using a proxy BUT when I go to simple: "show my IP websites" they give the correct one...

Comment: @Brad that's a good point. Wasn't sure though. My bad.

Comment: I tried this code and got a good result. Did you try making a PHP script that `var_dump`s `$_SERVER` and calling it directly in the browser? Are you sure that the IP is really the one of the server?

Comment: @bvl The remote address is **always** the address which has made a TCP connection to the server.  If you're using a proxy, that's the address of the proxy.  Most proxy servers pass on a header with the address of the end client.  `X-Forwarded-For` is most common.

Comment: @Brad I didn't know, but know I do, thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] does give you the IP address of the remote user. But if you are using a proxy or load balancer, you should use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

If users can reach your server directly or through a proxy then just use an if statement

```
$remote_ip = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

then pass the variable to JS.